# Installing Window 8.1 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8

How do I install Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox? VirtualBox keeps giving me this error:

```
 Failed to open a session for the virtual machine mywindow.

 VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).

 Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
 Component: Console
 Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}
```

Comment: So enable visualization in bios.

Comment: to see how it's done https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJYpT7L5ag ... it's similar on every machine

Answer (score 1):

Your machine's BIOS is currently disabling virtualization.

On startup, press enter (or equivalent for your machine) to enter the BIOS.

Locate the Virtualization option - for me, it's in the "Processor" menu.

There should be an option labelled something like "Virtualization Technology". I imagine it's disabled, if you're having this issue. Toggle it to be enabled, and you should be all set. :) I just had to use virtualbox for the first time last week, and I had the same issue. I hope this helps!